# How to view ctypes library of Python as text?

Tags: python, repository, shared-libraries, ctypes

I am working on using `ctypes` in various languages. I would like to look at the sourcecode of the crypes library in python in a text editor. Specifically I was looking helper functions of  `memmove`, `memset`, `string_at`, `wstring_at`. Based on that implementation I'll recreate the helper functions in my other languages.

I searched and came across these links here:

- http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=71702
- http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/old/index.html

But none of them have the library in text format so I can't view it. Can you please share with me link to like the github or hg repo where I can view the libraries code.

Comment: Why can't you search for it yourself? http://hg.python.org isn't hard to find.

Comment: I didn't know about that, I'm very new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTYPES can be found in the official mercurial repository for the source code of the Python language, in the appropriate folder. It can be seem through the web at this URL:

http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3134189655b1/Modules/_ctypes

Comment: I'm real new to repositories. The search on this page seems to search only "Changesets" or commit messages. Is it possible to search the code base?

Comment: Just click on the "browse" tab on the navigation menu at the left.

Comment: This is what I see when I click browse: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/oVSgo4O.png). Wow sorry for my total noob'ness. Right now Im downloading the whole codebase and doing a search in files. :(

Comment: It seems `memset` and `memmove` were removed recently apparently something with C89. So I'm trying to download the repo of ctypes 0.9.2 could you help me find that please, thats when these 4 helper functions first landed. Very sorry about this. The link above says `ctypes version 0.9.2 has been released (Oct 28, 2004):` so i found this closest commit on oct 28 2k4: http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/60c60dc75c77 i got here from: http://hg.python.org/cpython/shortlog/2fa872784eb6